# I’ll pay whomever can help me Bitcoin Cash from blockchain wallet to Coinbase wallet with Bitcoin address

Tags: blockchain, wallet, exchanges, bitcoin-cash, coinbase.com

I've read now a 100 or so questions here with no clearcut answer nor update after they were given advice. I had money in my Bitcoin Cash wallet on Blockchain. I wanted to send the money to my Coinbase account/wallet. No idea how I mixed/messed this up but I accidentally used my Bitcoin wallet address instead of Bitcoin Cash address.  I'm the owner of both accounts/wallets. It shows confirmation with Blockchain that it was sent (52 confirmations). I am too unfamiliar with the process with blockchain and coinbase to understand a lot of what people write as answers. I located the exact "address" that I accidentally used for the transfer from Blockchain to Coinbase. I called Coinbase and they basically said I'm dead water and it's gone (as most of the posts i've read on here state).  Is there a solution?  PLEASE help. >>>>I’ll gladly pay someone to help me figure this out<<<<  whomever can help me get a solution to this, I will gladly and guarantee to send them some of the proceeds

Comment: Offering payment for solutions is not how stack exchange works, and as I mentioned on your other post, unless you can get Coinbase to cooperate, your coins are inaccessible. No one else can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to Coinbase Support center they will surely help you because it's impossible to transfer your credit without there help

Answer (score 0):

In order to spend funds, you need to create a signature corresponding to the address that the funds previously got paid to. This requires the private key from which the address was derived. According to your information, this private key is held by Coinbase. Thus, you'll need to get Coinbase to help you, nobody else can.